# Function of array of pointers to abstract class returning an array

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'd like to create a generic integration library for my project, which would operate on different functions, with different integration methods. The idea is that I can call

```
next_step(:) = my_integration_function(previous_step, dt, args)
```

Here `next_step` is simply an array of coefficient (typically of type `real64`), while `previous_step` is an array of objects corresponding to functions at different time step, with their parameters (used to compute derivatives for instance).  So I need functions that operate on arrays of abstract classes, that can return arrays of `real` with a dimension depending on the function integrated, typically the first element of `previous_step`.

My problem is that I have a compiler segfault when I try to compile the following code with `gfortran 10.3` (Opensuse):

```
    module baseClass
      implicit none
    
      type, abstract, public :: base
         integer, allocatable :: i(:)
       contains
         procedure(sub), deferred, pass :: mysub
      end type base
    
      abstract interface
         subroutine sub(bb) 
           import :: base
           class(base), intent(in) :: bb
         end subroutine sub
      end interface
    
      type, public :: baseWrap
         class(base), pointer :: p
      end type baseWrap
    
      public :: operate_on_baseWrap
    
    contains
    
      function operate_on_baseWrap(wrapped) result(res)
        class(baseWrap), intent(in) :: wrapped(:)
    
        integer :: i, tmp
        integer, dimension(size(wrapped(1)%p%i)) :: res
    
        do i=1, size(wrapped)
           call wrapped(i)%p%mysub
        end do
    
        res = 0
      end function operate_on_baseWrap
    
    end module baseClass
    
    
    module childClass
      use baseClass
      implicit none
    
      type, extends(base), public :: child1
       contains
         procedure, pass :: mysub => sub_child1
      end type child1
    
    contains
    
      subroutine sub_child1(bb)
        class(child1), intent(in) :: bb
    
        print *, 'Do something', bb%i
      end subroutine sub_child1
    
    end module childClass
    
    
    program test
      use baseClass
      use childClass
      implicit none
    
      type(baseWrap), allocatable :: wrapper(:)
    
      type(child1), allocatable, target :: c(:)
    
      integer :: i
    
      integer, allocatable :: tmp(:)
      
      allocate(wrapper(3))
      allocate(c(3))
    
      do i=1, 3
         allocate(c(i)%i(3))
         c(i)%i = i
         wrapper(i)%p => c(i)
      end do
    
      allocate(tmp(size(wrapper(1)%p%i)))
      tmp = operate_on_baseWrap(wrapper)
    end program test
```

Here is the compiler error:

```
baseClass.f90:139:36:

  139 |   tmp = operate_on_baseWrap(wrapper)
      |                                    1
internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://bugs.opensuse.org/> for instructions.
```

Here `baseClass` would be the general integration library, and `child1` could be a specific function which I want to integrate.

The problem seems to come from `operate_on_baseWrap` returning an array, with a size given by one of the element of `wrapped` array.

Is it forbidden by the standard, or is it a compiler bug ?

Thanks for your insight !

Comment: "My problem is that I have a compiler segfault " - about any time (valid Fortran code or not) this happens it's a compiler bug.  What is the full message, if any, you get when compiling?

Comment: Even when a compiler segfaults on incorrect code, it is still a compiler bug. Unfortunately, there are still many in gfortran related to polymorphism.

Comment: I edited the post with the error from the compiler. It doesn't tell anything unfortunately. I'll report the bug then, I just wanted to make sure I am not doing anything forbidden by the standard. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @bdem Right thing to do - whenever you see "internal compiler error" it indicates a compiler error that should be reported